# HTTP Caching via Tables Latest modified time

Tags: http, postgresql, caching

I have a page that I wish to cache, the page displays the **list of recent comments and list of recent posts (both fetched from the DB)**

I plan to use `Last-Modified` in my `HTTP Headers` to implement caching, by setting the `Last-Modified` to the latest `updatedat` timestamp field from my DB

To get the latest modified time, would using a query such as

```
SELECT updatedat from comments, articles ORDER BY updateat DESC LIMIT 1
```

be efficient?

I would then compare the request's `If-Modified-Since` with the lastest timestamp from the `DB's (updatedat field)` to determine weather to re-load the data or just set the header type to `Not Modified (304)`

Comment: your query produces, as intermediate results, the Cartesian product of two tables;  what are you trying to query there?  do you want to know the latest date from both tables?

Comment: Yes, I wish to get the latest datetime (the greatest of either of the tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an index on the columns in question (updatedat) and then use the MAX function.

```
SELECT MAX(joint.updatedat) FROM (
    SELECT MAX(a.updatedat) updatedat FROM articles a
    UNION
    SELECT MAX(c.updatedat) updatedat FROM comments c
    ) joint;
```

Make sure that the queried column has an index, in *both* tables.

Comment: The comments table contains comments of articles and page (each page has a custom url and stands out from a article)

Comment: Your not going to be able to get the max from both tables like that, you need to determine the max in each separately, then select the greater of the two results.